# Convert XML file to LIST format (csv file)

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

Does anyone know how to convert an XML to a csv list? I have tried using linq but that for some reason doesn't work for me.

I have a file C:\temp\company_userlist.xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encodCompany="utf-8"?>

<VShell Version="4.0">

  <VirtualRoots Type="subkey">

    <VirtualRoot Type="subkey">

      <Path Type="strCompany"></Path>

      <Alias Type="strCompany"></Alias>

      <Comment Type="strCompany"></Comment>

      <MigratedPermissions Type="dword">2</MigratedPermissions>

      <Users Type="array"/>

    </VirtualRoot>

    <VirtualRoot Type="subkey">

      <Path Type="strCompany">D:\company_SFTP\files\Company-a</Path>

      <Alias Type="strCompany">CompanyA</Alias>

      <Comment Type="strCompany"></Comment>

      <MigratedPermissions Type="dword">2</MigratedPermissions>

      <Users Type="array">

        <Item Type="strCompany">Company_DOMAIN\SFTP Users Company Root Users,allow,use read write deletefile list create deletedir</Item>

        <Item Type="strCompany">Company_DOMAIN\FTP-1,allow,use read write deletefile list create deletedir</Item>

        <Item Type="strCompany">Company_DOMAIN\FTP-2,allow,use read write deletefile list create deletedir</Item>

        <Item Type="strCompany">Company_DOMAIN\FTP-ADMIN,allow,use read write deletefile list create deletedir</Item>

      </Users>

    </VirtualRoot>

    <VirtualRoot Type="subkey">

      <Path Type="strCompany">D:\company_SFTP\files\Company-AB1</Path>

      <Alias Type="strCompany">ADMINISSUER</Alias>

      <Comment Type="strCompany"></Comment>

      <MigratedPermissions Type="dword">2</MigratedPermissions>

      <Users Type="array">

        <Item Type="strCompany">Company_DOMAIN\SFTPDefaultIssuerRO,allow,use read list</Item>

      </Users>

    </VirtualRoot>

    <VirtualRoot Type="subkey">

      <Path Type="strCompany">D:\company_SFTP\files\Company-GB3</Path>

      <Alias Type="strCompany">XYZ3</Alias>

      <Comment Type="strCompany"></Comment>

      <MigratedPermissions Type="dword">2</MigratedPermissions>

      <Users Type="array">

        <Item Type="strCompany">Company_DOMAIN\FTPxyz3,allow,use read write deletefile list create deletedir</Item>

      </Users>

    </VirtualRoot>

    <VirtualRoot Type="subkey">

      <Path Type="strCompany">D:\company_SFTP\files\Company-RT4</Path>

      <Alias Type="strCompany">DFG-G</Alias>

      <Comment Type="strCompany"></Comment>

      <MigratedPermissions Type="dword">2</MigratedPermissions>

      <Users Type="array">

        <Item Type="strCompany">Company_DOMAIN\FTPABC,allow,use read write deletefile list create deletedir</Item>

      </Users>

    </VirtualRoot>

  <Install Type="subkey">

    <MainDirectory Type="strCompany">C:\Program Files\VanDyke Software\VShell\</MainDirectory>

  </Install>

</VShell>
```

I want the above sample to be converted into a list as per the below:

| Alias Type | Item Type | Path type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CompanyA | Company_DOMAIN\SFTP Users Company Root Users | D:\company_SFTP\files\Company-a |
| CompanyA | Company_DOMAIN\FTP-1 | D:\company_SFTP\files\Company-a |
| CompanyA | Company_DOMAIN\FTP-2 | D:\company_SFTP\files\Company-a |
| CompanyA | Company_DOMAIN\FTP-ADMIN | D:\company_SFTP\files\Company-a |
| ADMINISSUER | Company_DOMAIN\SFTPDefaultIssuerRO | D:\company_SFTP\files\Company-AB1 |
| XYZ3 | Company_DOMAIN\FTPxyz3 | D:\company_SFTP\files\Company-GB3 |
| DFG-G | Company_DOMAIN\FTPABC | D:\company_SFTP\files\Company-RT4 |

Answer (score 2):

Start by enumerating all the `<VirtualRoot />` elements we want to extract data from:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content C:\temp\company_userlist.xml)
$xml.SelectNodes('//VirtualRoot')
```

Then we need to flatten the `<Users />` child element and create an object object for each `<Item />` child.

We can do the first flattening step with `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` as follows:

```
$xml.SelectNodes('//VirtualRoot') |Select-Object Alias,Path -ExpandProperty Users
```

Now we just need to iterate over each `<Item />` element and construct some output objects, and we end up with something like this:

```
$objects = $xml.SelectNodes('//VirtualRoot') |Select-Object Alias,Path -ExpandProperty Users |% {
  foreach($item in $_.Item |Where-Object {$_.Item}) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
      'Alias Type' = $_.Alias.InnerText
      'Item Type' = $item.InnerText -replace ',.*$'
      'Path Type' = $_.Path.InnerText
    }
  }
}
```

The `... |Where-Object {$_.Item}` pipeline element will filter out nodes with empty `<Item />` elements, and `-replace ',.*$'` will remove everything after the first comma in each of the contained permission strings, leaving you with just the principal name.

The resulting set of objects thus ends up looking like:

```
Alias Type  Item Type                                    Path Type
----------  ---------                                    ---------
CompanyA    Company_DOMAIN\SFTP Users Company Root Users D:\company_SFTP\files\Company-a
CompanyA    Company_DOMAIN\FTP-1                         D:\company_SFTP\files\Company-a
CompanyA    Company_DOMAIN\FTP-2                         D:\company_SFTP\files\Company-a
CompanyA    Company_DOMAIN\FTP-ADMIN                     D:\company_SFTP\files\Company-a
ADMINISSUER Company_DOMAIN\SFTPDefaultIssuerRO           D:\company_SFTP\files\Company-AB1
XYZ3        Company_DOMAIN\FTPxyz3                       D:\company_SFTP\files\Company-GB3
DFG-G       Company_DOMAIN\FTPABC                        D:\company_SFTP\files\Company-RT4
```

Nice flat objects easily exported to a CSV file:

```
$objects |Export-Csv path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: thanks mate. I am getting the error below though:

Comment: Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'SelectNodes'.
At line:3 char:1
+ $objects = $xml.SelectNodes('//VirtualRoot') |Select-Object Alias,Pat ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: @DanGoodwin Sorry, I assumed you'd have read the XML document into a variable named `$xml`, I've updated the first code block to show how you could do that

Comment: I did try that as a code block, as below:

$xml = [xml](Get-Content C:\temp\company_userlist.xml)

however I was getting this error:

Comment: Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 1, position 4."
At line:1 char:1
+ $xml = [xml](Get-Content C:\temp\company_userlist.xml)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToXmlDocument

Comment: So i assumed this was incorrect. So I used the code:

$xml = 'C:\temp\company_userlist.xml'

but that produced the errors i showed earlier.

Comment: @DanGoodwin There are a couple of errors in the XML document you've posted - `encodCompany` instead of `encoding` in the declaration, it lacks a closing tag for `</VirtualRoots>`, etc.. Did you copy-paste the data around from elsewhere?

Comment: okay that was my fault as the file has empty lines and spaces at the beginning. I am now getting this error. Sorry for this, I am new to working with xml files in powershell. So trying to pick up as much as I can

Comment: Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "Syntax for an XML declaration is invalid. Line 1, position 21."

Comment: As I said, your XML declaration has an invalid attribute `encodCompany`, should be `encoding`

Comment: I'd strongly suggest going back to the source (whatever sample file you're working with) and copy that over to your development environment again

Comment: I have fixed the errors now mate. thank you for your help!! It appears that it was missing a closing tag, which is bazar as this xml was generated from an export vshell command